# Rails: Have initializer load before application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, initialization

I have an initializer named _settings.rb that looks like this

```
class Settings < Settingslogic
    source "#{Rails.root}/config/application.yml"

    namespace Rails.env
end
```

My application.yml defines a value for a custom setting I call environhost.
I call it using:

```
   Settings.environhost
```

This works fine, EXCEPT for when I try to call the value in my /app/config/application.rb

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = Settings.environhost
```

For this, I get an uninitialized constant.

Is there anyway I can put a pointer in my application.rb to load _settings.rb before

```
 config.action_controller.asset_host = Settings.environhost
```

is loaded?  What's the best way to do this?

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html

Comment: related on the wiki: https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic/wiki/Use-Settings-in-your-Rails-initializers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails own configuration will be always loaded before any custom things, that's for sure. Otherwise can you imagine what a mess :)

The solution is not to try to load before Rails configuration. Instead, hook into initializer to add your own logic to override Rails default.

[Railtie](http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/railties/lib/rails/railtie_rb.html) is the place you can do that without sweat. Here you can access `config` method shared in all initializers including Rails.

```
module MySettings
  def self.environhost
    "foobar"
  end

  class MySettingsRailtie < Rails::Railtie
    config.action_controller.asset_host = MySettings.environhost
  end
end
```

Side note: In most cases you should be fine to set assets host as mu_is_too_short commented. If you need anything other than that, you can use custom intializer by Railtie.

Comment: interesting.  i'm going to try this tomorrow morning! If it works I'll let you know and mark the answer!

Comment: thanks this works, and you're right, i don't know why i didn't think of configuring it in the separate environments.  thanks though, this lets me bypass that :)